# problem in using Distinct with Linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq, distinct

Hi have an issue with Linq. I have an array of double values with duplicate entries. I want to extract only distinct values from it. I have the following code which doesn't work correctly.

```
double[] dIds = GetIds(); //dIds has more than 10,000 items

var itemIdCollection = from id in dIds.Distinct()
                   select id;

Console.WriteLine(itemIdCollection.count().ToString());  //count is just 2 !!!!
```

Can you please give me a solution on this?

Thank you,

Comment: what were you expecting it to return and why?

Comment: Have you ever looked at the content of dIds?

Comment: Why is `count` written with a lowercase C? Is this your real code?

Comment: Are you using doubles as Ids? Floating point numbers and equality are not great friends...

Answer (score 1):

First off, you don't have to do that freaky select.  Just call `dIds.Distinct()`.  Second, I can guarantee you that it works on any array of doubles.  Your doubles are NOT different from everybody else's doubles.

Obviously, if Distinct() is returning an enumerable of a count of 2 (btw, `Console.WriteLine(itemIdCollection.Count())` is sufficient) it is because `GetIds()` returns an array containing only two distinct doubles.

Your assumptions, they are incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
List<double> x = new List<double>()
{
    3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8
};

List<double> distinct = x.Distinct().ToList();

distinct.ForEach(y => Console.WriteLine(y));
Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: ForEach extension doesn't belong to .Net standard libraries...you should provide it (even if very simple to find or implement)

Comment: ForEach is an extension on Lists provided with Linq as part of .NET.

Comment: Sorry, I dislike it so much that I've forgotten its esistence. :P

Comment: ForEach is not an extension on lists and is not a part of LINQ. It's a perfectly ordinary method on the list type.

Comment: Yup, you're right! That's my mistake, everything that looks like a Linq query I tend to call a Linq method without knowing better =D

Answer (score 0):

#### Ghost debugging attempt:

Are you generating new random IDs in your `GetIds()` function? If so, remember you should be instantiating `Random` outside the function...